# How do I import a set of symbols in Sketch 3?

Tags: symbols, sketch-app

How do I import symbols from one project into another.  For instance, I've downloaded the [Bootstrap 3 resource](http://www.sketchappsources.com/free-source/457-bootstrap-v3-gui.html), and I want to bring the symbols into another project I'm working on without copying and pasting one by one.

Comment: One way I've found is to save the Bootstrap project as a template, then open a new project from that template, but this method doesn't work with existing projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Sketch *Symbols* and *Shared Styles* work across pages, but not cross-document.

- One way is to have a page (symbols page) with all the symbols you
  need and copy only the necessary for each project.
- A second approach (actually is the technique I've been using) is
  to have a template with two pages, one for all the symbols and
  another blank page in the       same file. So, you only have to start
  every project by creating a new     file based on this template.

Comment: UPDATE: this does not work since the new symbols on 3.7

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Actually I used to have a page with symbols inside my main file, but one day I accidentally deleted half of them without any chance to restore. Other funny thing that I figured out is that dropbox history doesn't work with sketch 3. I tried to restore earlier file version from dropbox, but it didn't work. In other words, it is safer to keep your symbols in a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is what you are looking for, but it can be an easy way to start with a template of your symbols and not have to copy and paste each time you want to create a new document.

http://medialoot.com/blog/custom-templates-and-reusable-symbol-libraries-in-sketch/

I hope this help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You might try the Sketch Import Symbols plugin (https://github.com/kmerc/sketch-import-symbols). Unfortunately it doesn't work for me - but that might be my setup.

Comment: And is it to use? Suppose the link is down then your answer with a link is not very helpful ...

Comment: didn't work for me either. any other way?

Answer (score 0):

What I've found works is to create a new page ("shared symbols") in my new document select all the symbols I need from my source document FROM THE LEFT HAND MENU, then copy them and paste them onto my new page. They're available as symbols to insert in my new document.